# Более безопасное логгирование *url.URL с паролем в user info

Tags: golang, безопасность, логирование

Есть некий `*net/url.URL`, который может содержать пароль
в *user info*. Логгировать этот пароль
не хочется. Есть ли какой-то встроенный способ сделать
логгирование более безопасным?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Go 1.15* добавил метод
[`*net/url.URL.Redacted`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url#URL.Redacted),
который работает как `*net/url.URL.String`,
но заменяет пароль, если он есть, на `xxxxx`:

```golang
fmt.Println(u)
// Output:
//
//   https://user:password@example.com
fmt.Println(u.Redacted())
// Output:
//
//   https://user:xxxxx@example.com
```

Рекомендую сделать обёртку, чтобы метод `String` всегда
возвращал *URL* без пароля:

```golang
type SecureURL url.URL

func (u *SecureURL) String() (s string) {
	return (*url.URL)(u).Redacted()
}

// …

fmt.Println(u)
// Output:
//
//   https://user:xxxxx@example.com
```